# Grub menu won't show up after I did dual boot

Tags: grub2

I did a partition after uninstalling Ubuntu and now that I installed Kali Linux it does not boot into GRUB; it just boots directly into Windows.

I do not have the option to boot into Kali Linux, GRUB menu won't show even though I have Kali Linux install.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually check in the boot menu for booting into Kali.
Or. 
If that doesn't work, Supergrub2 is always an option :) 
Try booting Kali with your Supergrub2 booted device and update the grub.

Link:https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/

Answer (score 0):

If you have dual boot and any of the above steps aren't working, this might come in handy for you.

- Get a Windows OS installation DVD, borrow it from your friend or anyone. (Don’t get windows XP or Vista DVD.)
- Launch it on your PC and run the installer.

This can be done by selecting boot medium either by pressing F12 or by setting boot order in your bootloader.

It can be accessed by pressing F2 or Del. or any key your manufacturer suggests.

- After all your Windows files are loaded then select repair your computer.

Usually, this option appears at bottom of dialog box after selecting a couple of options.

- If prompted select OS, then in system recovery option choose command prompt. 

  Now enter these commands one by one:

  ```
  bootrec /fixboot
  bootrec /fixmbr
  ```

Now quit setup and reboot the PC/Laptop.
The windows boot is restored and has overridden GRUB.

Still, your Linux distro is present there. Only GRUB has overridden.

You may again get back it by following:

- Get a Live USB stick. I will prefer Ubuntu Live USB stick.
- Open terminal after booting up into the live desktop.
- Mount the root partition by typing /mnt and boot to /mnt/boot and hit enter.

[e.g. sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda]

You should replace /dev/sda with correct partition or disk.

- Now update grub by typing:

  ```
  sudo update-grub.
  ```

It can take some time so wait. 

After successful update reboot

Problem solved.